# Combining ordinal variables and what statistical test to use

Tags: spss, survey, ordinal-data, likert

I have heard a lot of different opinions on this matter, which led to some confusion on my side.

I have ordinal data that was captured in a survey with a 5-point Likert scale (Strongly disagree, disagree, neutral, agree, strongly agree). I now have 3 sets of ordinal items and each set can be combined into a new single variable. This has also been checked by a reliability analysis.

I would calculate the mean of a set of variables to arrive at my new single variable. Some scientific studies claim that the mean can be calculated, while other studies do not recommend this method. However, I need to somehow combine each set to do further statistical testing. I was thinking about using Ordinal Regression and Spearman Correlation to test the new variables.

Maybe someone worked on something similar and has some suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What questions do you want to answer?

Comment: In my view this depends on the exact meaning of the data and what question you want them to address, of which not much is explained.

Comment: "Some scientific studies claim that the mean can be calculated, while other studies do not recommend this method. " That's not a contradiction. Of course the mean *can* be calculated, but whether that's a good idea is an entirely different matter. Personally I'm not dead against it, it really depends on the exact circumstances.

Comment: The questions mainly capture the attachment of respondents to their environment (independent variable) and attitude toward specific man-made structures in the landscape (dependent). Let's say I would calculate the mean to arrive at the mentioned independent and dependent variables, could the mean scores be used in an ordinal regression ? I am not sure if the new variables and their mean scores are still regarded as ordinal.

Comment: The controversy arises because you cannot average ordinal categorical variables without pretending that the ordinal labels are numbers. In effect, you ultimately have a numerical variable variable; the controversy arises from doubts that the 'averaged' **pretend-numerical** variables really obey all of the rules of truly numerical variables. IMHO the social science literature is littered with false discoveries from betting the answer is Yes.